# Ассемблерные вставки в Delphi

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

Вставляю код сортировки в `Delphi` написанную на `ASM`. В консоли вылазит ошибка

> Runtime error 216 at 00403AE5

В чем может быть проблема? Читал, что ошибка из-за неправильного обращения к памяти, но никак не могу придумать и понять, как это можно исправить.

```delphi
program Project2;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

const N=2;
type TArr = array[1..N] of integer;
var Arr:TArr;
  i:integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to N do readln(Arr[i]);
  asm
    @vozv:
        mov si,1
        mov ecx,N
        mov edx,1
    @sort:
        xor eax,eax
        mov eax,dword[Arr[si]]
        cmp eax,dword[Arr[si+1]]
        jnl @skiper
        xchg eax,dword[Arr[si+1]]
        mov dword[Arr[si]],eax
        xor edx,edx
    @skiper:
        inc si
      loop @sort
        or edx, edx
        jz @vozv
  end;
  for i:=1 to N do write(Arr[i], ' ');
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался проще, чем кажется. Все время писал на `FASM`, а `Delphi` просит `TASM` и использует другой синтаксис команд.

```
program Laba_asm;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

const N=5;
type TArr = array[1..N] of integer;
var Arr:TArr;
  i:integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to N do readln(Arr[i]);
  asm
    @vozv:
        mov si,1
        mov ecx,N
        mov edx,1
        lea eax, dword ptr[Arr]
    @sort:
        xor ebx,ebx
        mov ebx,dword ptr[eax]
        cmp ebx,dword ptr[eax+4]
        jnl @skiper
        xchg ebx,eax+4
        mov dword ptr[eax],ebx
        xor edx,edx
    @skiper:
        add eax, 4
      loop @sort
        or edx, edx
        jz @vozv
  end;
  for i:=1 to N do write(Arr[i], ' ');
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: А то, что этот код не сортирует, не волнует?

Comment: @MBo, не знаю как у вас, у меня - сортирует.

Comment: Возможно, у меня что-то не в порядке. В Debug режиме шалит так: `5 1 6 2 7 => 7 6 6 5 2`, в release вывод верный

Comment: и даже так `5 4 3 2 1 => 6 5 4 3 2`